# How to find the rows which are NOT found in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a 1-1 column relation between two tables, `item` and `log`

For each item, there's a log which stores whether item has been processed or not. This is identified by `log.itemId` being equal to `item.id`. `log.status` tells if the processing is in progress, or has finished (-1 being pending, 1 being finished).

Before processing starts, there's no row in the `log` table for the corresponding item in `item` table.

I'm trying simply to get the rows from item where either there's no corresponding row in log (meaning processing hasn't started) or where status is not 1 (meaning its pending).

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out, this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    item.id
FROM item, log
WHERE log.itemId != item.id
OR (log.itemId = item.id AND log.status !='1')
ORDER BY item.id ASC LIMIT 1
```

However this returns an empty result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want all the rows, why do have the `limit 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  item.id
FROM
  item left join log on (log.itemId = item.id)
WHERE
  log.itemId is null
  OR log.status !='1'
ORDER BY item.id LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer provided works and is very common (an outer join and a check for NULL on the outer table), there is another approach in SQL that more directly applies:

```
SELECT
item.id
FROM item
WHERE
not exists
    (SELECT itemID from log where log.itemID = item.id and log.status = '1')
```

I would recommend trying both and determining which operates faster -- the outer join check for NULL vs. the "not exists" syntax.  Most databases do not optimize the two queries the same (even though the results are identical), so one will likely outperform the other, although it's not always obvious which is better.

NOTE that I changed the != to = in the last line, but I think that is correct, although I may have misunderstood the logic.

Answer (score 1):

One of the decision is using EXISTS (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), the example you find below or you can use LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT *
FROM item AS i
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM log AS l
    WHERE l.itemId = i.id
        AND l.status != 1
)
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Comment: With an index on `l.itemId` and a `limit 1` clause in the subquery, this should be the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this:

```
SELECT item.id FROM item WHERE item.id NOT IN (SELECT itemid FROM log where log.status != '1')
```

Comment: This does not deserve an upvote, because it does not answer the question correctly.